# Perl Modules - Migrate / Deploy across Hosts

Tags: perl, module, installation

I have what I hope is a simple question that I haven't, for the life of me, been able to find across the web.

Q: Is there a quick / standard automated way to duplicate all the perl modules on a system A to another system B running an identical version of Linux (say Fedora or centOS), assuming the modules on host A are all pretty standard modules (no home growns) such as would be retrieved from CPAN?

I'm sorry if this is an incredibly dumb question - every time I search for something I get answers relating to perl installed modules listings, but nothing on how to use this to automate a re-install or create a mirrored installation on another system.

Any help is much appreciated - love this site!

R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [autobundle package](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-depperl/index.html) to achieve an installation script of sorts for mass system deployments.

Comment: 20.Bundles and System Administration Bundles are a very convenient way to maintain homogeneous installations across multiple systems, including across architectures Personal experience: create bundles for local and external modules; store bundles in a repository; checkout and install sequentially on development, test and production servers; single install experience, guaranteed homogeneity 20

Comment: Thanks - I knew it had to be something standard!